# svn; detect missing revisions between different branches

Tags: svn, branch, relationship, detect, revision

Is there a way to setup relationships between the SVN branches so that we can detect if there are any missing revisions?

We have multiple developers working on different branches (A,B,C) and fixes made in some of these branches (e.g. A) need to be merged/reapplied into other branches (e.g. B, C). 
There have been occassions where a developer someone has forgotten to reapply the fixes in other branch (e.g. B, C) consequently resulting in build/test failure in ther other branches.

Trying to find a way (maybe utility, script) to relate various branches and in turn get notifications in case a revision applied in branch A is missing from branch B or C.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project that involved something very similar: to determine if branches were missing merges based on some reference point (usually trunk).

I'm unaware of any tool that would do this, but it should be fairly easy to whip up a little command-line tool that reads `svn:mergeinfo` and does a compare of revisions between two branches to determine if one requires a merge from the other. In C#, I would use the [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) library.

I don't know what your branching or merging methodology is, but if I needed to merge changes from `branch A`, I would always branch it (and any other branches) off `trunk`, merge its changes back into `trunk`, then merge `trunk` up into the other branches (`branch B` and `branch C`). So, `trunk` becomes the reference point to use to determine if a merge is needed. I would avoid cross-branch merges if at all possible.

Hope this helps.